# How to center Element which have display property inline block i use margin left and right auto but it is not work?

Tags: css, margin, center

I use `margin: 0px auto;` in **`display : inline-block`** but my element is unable to comes in center but when i use `display : block` it comes in center.

```css
.container {
  background-color: beige;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  This is Container
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: inline-block` will make the container to flow on the way as the same way as inline elements like `span` flows. To center as inline-block container you have to provide `text-align: center` to parent container.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>CSS TUTORIAL - Border</title>

  <style>
    body {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .container {
      background-color: beige;
      border: 1px solid red;
      width: 250px;
      height: 200px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    This is Container
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to add this style to body class

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS TUTORIAL - Border</title>

    <style>
      body {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .container {
      background-color: beige;
      border: 1px solid red;
      width: 250px;
      height: 200px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" >
          This is Container
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
text-align:center;
```

Comment: it is not work but when i use text-align center in body tag than it is work

Answer (score 0):

**why is working with `block`?**

If you use `display: block` will be taking 100% of the space and then center it `auto`.

[image]

> like you see in the image before there is that orange color (space) because it takes up 100% of space.

**why is NOT working with `inline-block`?**

an `inline` element takes less space, so technically the `auto` value will be set to **0**

[image]

---

> **how to center:**
>
>  follow the other answer for how to center with:
>
>  `flex` or `grid`: @kunal's answer
>
>  or `text-align`: @ardan's answer
>
>  
> I tried to tell you why is not working :)